# NFS access from multiple networks

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

On my NFS server (Ubuntu) I have in `/etc/exports` the following:

```
/share 192.168.89.1/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)
```

However, I have a new machine which is not in `192.168.89.*` IP range, it's in `192.168.92.*` instead. How can I make this machine access my NFS server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[You can specify multiple IP ranges on a line](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/server.html), separated by spaces:

```
/share 192.168.89.1/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)  192.168.92.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)
```

See the [exports man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) for some more examples (Scroll down to "Examples").